# Audio won't play until you change the value of the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using this for a volume slider and it's working. But I need to change the slider or it won't play the audio. I even changed the value to 50 but it still won't play until you adjust the slider.
Any help would be great

```
$("#volume").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 0,
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        setVolume((ui.value) / 100);
    }
});

var myMedia = document.createElement('audio');
$('#player').append(myMedia);
myMedia.id = "myMedia";
playAudio('http://iviewsource.com/exercises/audioslider/audio/ViewSource', 0);

function playAudio(fileName, myVolume) {
    var mediaExt = (myMedia.canPlayType('audio/mp3')) ? '.mp3' : (myMedia.canPlayType('audio/ogg')) ? '.ogg' : '';
    if (mediaExt) {
        myMedia.src = fileName + mediaExt;
        myMedia.setAttribute('loop', 'loop');
        setVolume(myVolume);
        myMedia.play();
    }
}

function setVolume(myVolume) {
    var myMedia = document.getElementById('myMedia');
    myMedia.volume = myVolume;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your player is muted at the beginning. Maybe that's Your issue?

If You change the starting volume value to 1, You should hear the music.

```
var initialVolume = 1;
...
playAudio('http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major', initialVolume);
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h48x22vv/1/).

Another tip could be: is Your code executed when document is ready or before?

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Can't belive I didn't notice that.